# Handler block is called twice automatically and image downloads twice issue

Tags: objective-c, handler

```
[HTTPReq postRequestWithPath:@"" class:nil parameters:dictRequest completionBlock:^(id result, NSError *error) {
   if (result)
   {
     NSDictionary *dictResult = result;    
      if([[dictResult valueForKey:@"message"] isEqualToString:@"success"]){
      //if success i download the image..
   }
```

Comment: Could it be the definition of `postRequestWithPath:class:parameters: completionBlock:` that call its completion block twice?

Comment: @Larme No, its not the case because there are 3 cases and only in one case the completionBlock is called twice automatically

Comment: @Larme +(IQURLConnection*)postRequestWithPath:(NSString*)path class:(Class)klass object:(id)requestObj  completionBlock:(HTTPReqObjectCompletion)completionBlock {
    NSDictionary *parameters = nil;
    if ([requestObj isKindOfClass:[Serializable class]]) {
        parameters = [requestObj toDictionary];
    }
    else if ([requestObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        parameters = (NSDictionary*)requestObj;
    }
    return  [HTTPReq postRequestWithPath:path class:klass parameters:parameters completionBlock:completionBlock];
}

Comment: Please edit your question. I'm was asking about the method `+postRequestWithPath:class:parameters:completionBlock:` of `HTTPReq` (the `return` line)

Comment: @Larme, the return line calls to different method

Comment: What's the code of that method?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. The solution is to cache the image which is being downloaded.